# SMSManager for chinese, Nullpointer

Tags: android, smsmanager

I'm trying to send a sms with chinese characters using SMSManager. It works fine for english and german, but unfortunately not for chinese.

My Log:

```
    01-07 20:23:56.200: W/System.err(15742): java.lang.NullPointerException
01-07 20:23:56.200: W/System.err(15742):    at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1266)
01-07 20:23:56.204: W/System.err(15742):    at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1248)
01-07 20:23:56.204: W/System.err(15742):    at com.android.internal.telephony.ISms$Stub$Proxy.sendText(ISms.java:561)
01-07 20:23:56.204: W/System.err(15742):    at android.telephony.SmsManager.sendTextMessage(SmsManager.java:109)
01-07 20:23:56.204: W/System.err(15742):    at com.app.myapp.MainActivity.sendSms(MainActivity.java:158)
01-07 20:23:56.204: W/System.err(15742):    at com.app.myapp.MainActivity.buttonClick(MainActivity.java:103)
01-07 20:23:56.204: W/System.err(15742):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
01-07 20:23:56.204: W/System.err(15742):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
01-07 20:23:56.204: W/System.err(15742):    at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:2067)
01-07 20:23:56.204: W/System.err(15742):    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:2408)
01-07 20:23:56.204: W/System.err(15742):    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:8818)
01-07 20:23:56.204: W/System.err(15742):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
01-07 20:23:56.204: W/System.err(15742):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
01-07 20:23:56.204: W/System.err(15742):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
01-07 20:23:56.204: W/System.err(15742):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
01-07 20:23:56.208: W/System.err(15742):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
01-07 20:23:56.208: W/System.err(15742):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
01-07 20:23:56.208: W/System.err(15742):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:871)
01-07 20:23:56.208: W/System.err(15742):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:629)
01-07 20:23:56.208: W/System.err(15742):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

And this is how I send the SMS

```
SmsManager smsManager = SmsManager.getDefault();
                    for (int i = 0; i < numbers.size(); i++) {
                        smsManager.sendTextMessage(numbers.get(i), null,
                                message, null, null);
                    }
```

Any ideas? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Where does message come from? Is it inputted by the user? Is it properly coded?

Comment: Thanks for answer. message comes from string resources: 

message = getResources().getString(R.string.msg)

It is properly coded. As said in my post it works fine for english and german.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, I could solved it just limiting the number of characters. In English, 160 characters are allowed. In Chinese, only 70 characters can be used (each character takes more bytes to be represented).

So, to test it, just replace message with message.substring(0, 69) and it will work.

To properly solve the proble, splitted messages must be sent, check:
http://www.programering.com/a/MTM4EjMwATE.html